# matplotlib.widgets Slider displays the slider but they don't do anything, it's just a png

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a problem where I am plotting a circle and want to use a slider to adjust the values that define the circle, but the plot/sliders are just a .png file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

B=1
w=1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)

t = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.02)
x = (B/w)*np.sin(w*t)
y = (B/w)*np.cos(w*t)-(B/w)
l, = plt.plot(x, y)

axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
axamplitude = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

freq = Slider(axfreq, 'Frequency', 0.0, 20.0, 3)

amplitude = Slider(axamplitude, 'Amplitude', 0.0, 10.0, 5, valstep=1.0)

def update(val):
    f = freq.val
    a = amplitude.val

freq.on_changed(update)
amplitude.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you running this in a notebook environment? If so, you'll need to use an interactive backend by using something like `%matplotlib qt` at the beginning of your notebook/cell.

Comment: That'll do it! Added ```import ipympl``` ```%matplotlib widget``` at the beginning and it works now, thank you!!

Comment: I will submit a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in a notebook environment, you need to use an interactive backend with `%matplotlib qt`